# Lambda using API Gateway providing incorrect CORS response

Tags: caching, cors, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a **Lambda deployed behind an API Gateway within AWS**, with the API cache enabled.

It has been configured using the standard *Enable CORS* option, which has created a header mapping for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` on the *OPTIONS* method.

However when the API is called to execute a method on the Lambda, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response is being set to the `origin` header from the request.

This is causing a problem as I've selected *Enable API cache*.

It appears this is causing a responses to be cached with domain specific  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`  responses. i.e. not  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, but instead  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {whatever the origin header of the request was`

This is causing CORS failures from the client.

I cannot find any documentation about this behavior and why this is happening?

Comment: If you can cause a `Vary` response header with the value `Origin` to also be added to the responses, then when the value of the `Origin` request header is different from the `Origin` value of the request it was cached from, that should have the effect of causing the cache to be skipped, and a new network request to be made instead.

See [the relevant part of the HTTP spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.4) and [the MDN article on `Vary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary).

Comment: I don't believe this is possible @sideshowbarker when a Lambda is used with an API Gateway. The ability to set response headers within AWS is removed.

Answer (score 0):

The CORS response was being generated within the Lambda, not the API Gateway.

The flask-cors library used by the Python based Lambda was incorrectly set.

As per the documentation:

> send_wildcard (bool) – If True, and the origins parameter is *, a
>   wildcard Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is sent, rather than the
>   request's Origin header.
>
> Default : False

So in the code

```
CORS(app)
```

has been changed to

```
CORS(app, send_wildcard=True)
```

and I know get the behavior I want, which is for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header response to be `*`